# resove #define conflict with structure member

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, member, conflict

in a pre-existing code, I have some #define that point to bitfields like these:

```
#define OUT0 PORT1.DR.B1
#define OUT1 PORT1.DR.B4
```

I need to add a structure with this name to the cpp file:

```
struct {
    unsigned char OUT0: 1;
    unsigned char OUT1: 1;
    unsigned char OUT2: 1;
    unsigned char OUT3: 1;
    unsigned char OUT4: 1;
    unsigned char OUT5: 1;
    unsigned char OUT6: 1;
    unsigned char OUT7: 1;
} expander;
```

obviously the compiler signals me an error because the preprocessor replaces OUT0 and OUT1 in the expander structure.

I cannot change the name of the members of the structure because they must coincide with the labels of the product it manages.

the obvious solution would be to change the member's name to something like:

```
struct {
    unsigned char OUT0_: 1;
    unsigned char OUT1_: 1;
    unsigned char OUT2_: 1;
    unsigned char OUT3_: 1;
    unsigned char OUT4_: 1;
    unsigned char OUT5_: 1;
    unsigned char OUT6_: 1;
    unsigned char OUT7_: 1;
} expander;
```

but these '_' , at the end, are truly horrible.

(if PORT1.DR.B1 and PORT1.DR.B4 were not bitfields, i could replace the #defines with const pointers:

```
unsigned char * const OUT0 = &PORT1.DR.B1;
unsigned char * const OUT1 = &PORT1.DR.B4;
```

but even this is not possible beacause they are bitfields)

is there any other solution?

Comment: Having generic short 4 character identifer in file scope seems like a bad idea. Why not rename `OUTx` macros to something better? I doubt that you have too many uses of I/O pin name in the code, so it shouldn't be too much work.

Comment: Assuming the structure is visible only in 1 cpp file, can you just `#undef` the macros before the structure definition?

Comment: the length of the define in this context is not a problem as there are no other conflicts. I understand that renaming would be the simplest solution but I preferred not to change the name of the #define or the members of the struct. I wanted to understand if there was another solution.

Comment: [zkoza] the problem is that the #define OUT0 OUT1 and the members of the "expander" structure are processed in a mixed way in the same function

Answer (score 0):

> is there any other solution?

No.

Instead of putting `_` on the end of member variable names (which as you stated is `truly horrible`, to which I want to note, that it's truly fine and ok), you can put something else in front or the end of variables.

You can also `#undef` the macros.

You can also define the structure before defining the macros.

Overall, all solutions are cumbersome, and the best is to just use unique names, everywhere. Pick different names for your structure members - for example, with `_` on the end.